# default route for interface configured during PXE boot

Tags: pxe-boot, route, sles

I've got some systems that are provisioning SLES12sp1 statelessly - the systems come up with their provisioning interface configured, but no default route.

On RedHat I'd set the `GATEWAYDEV` in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` -- but I can't find an equivalent for openSUSE/SLES.

There is no NetworkManager, Wicked or `ifcfg` files:

```
# ls /etc/sysconfig/network/
config  dhcp  if-down.d  if-up.d  ifcfg-lo  ifcfg.template  network  providers  scripts
```

Some additional context:

```
# ifconfig eth2
eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  
          inet addr:192.168.1.29  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::21e:67ff:fecb:f26f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:213248 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:35744 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:295970393 (282.2 Mb)  TX bytes:4018621 (3.8 Mb)
          Memory:92020000-9203ffff 

# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0     U     0      0        0 eth2
```

I've tried creating a `routes` and `ifroute-ethX` files with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried passing DHCP option 3 during the PXE boot ?

Comment: I think normally this would work -- but as a side effect of how my system is being provisioned it doesn't solve my case. I think this particular issue is beyond the scope of PXE/DHCP/SLES.